# Flex Spark List component item order

Tags: apache-flex, list, sorting, actionscript

I have a regular spark list which is sorted correctly when no item renderer is used. However, when the following item renderer is used, the list shuffles and displays items from previous instances of the list. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                autoDrawBackground="true"
                creationComplete="itemRendererInit(event)">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import flash.utils.setInterval;

        import flashx.textLayout.conversion.TextConverter;

        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        protected function itemRendererInit(event:FlexEvent):void {
            setInterval(resizeItemRenderer, 50);
            richtext.textFlow= TextConverter.importToFlow(
                '<TextFlow xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/textLayout/2008"><linkNormalFormat color="#ac0000" textDecoration="none"/><linkHoverFormat color="#ac0000" textDecoration="underline"/><linkActiveFormat color="#ac0000" textDecoration="none"/><p><span fontWeight="bold">' +
                data[0].toString() +
                ':</span><br/><br/>' +
                data[1].toString() +
                '</p></TextFlow>', TextConverter.TEXT_LAYOUT_FORMAT);
        }

        private function resizeItemRenderer():void {
            richtext.width = parentApplication.width-525;
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:RichEditableText id="richtext"
            paddingBottom="10" paddingLeft="10" paddingRight="10" paddingTop="10"
            verticalAlign="middle" editable="false" textAlign="left"/>

</s:ItemRenderer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found it to be a data binding problem. Thanks @M.D.

Answer (score 0):

Just over the top of my head, try overriding commitProperties instead of relying on creationComplete event. On creationComplete, just call invalidateProperties and then call your function from commitProperties().